# c# Textbox filling with dataset from MYsql?

Tags: c#, mysql, textbox

I am trying to populate some text boxes on a form with data pulled from MySQL into a data set.
I cant seem to get the code right and could use some help

```
        string ConnectionString = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["ConnectionString"];
        MySqlConnection connection;
        MySqlDataAdapter adapter;
        DataTable DTItems;



        connection = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString);

        try
        {
            //prepare query to get all records from items table
            string query = "select * from spt_proposal where fr_Numer = "+ a+"";



            //prepare adapter to run query
            adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(query, connection);
            DataSet DS = new DataSet();
            //get query results in dataset
            adapter.Fill(DS);
            textBox5.Text = DS.Tables[0].Rows[0].ToString();
```

This does not hit the text box at all.

a in the query is a variable that is pulled from a different form

and the query should pull 32 different things from the database in a row

There are about 9 text boxes on the form that i will have to fill with different data from this row.

Anyone have a better way to do this?

Brent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
textBox5.Text = DS.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString();
```

Remember, that a Table is pretty much a two dimensional array.  Your code literally gets to the 1st row in the DataSet, but doesn't take into account the Column.

Comment: That still does not work i put a break point at the textbox and it does not stop but the line before it does and if i drop the where the textbox is just blank. but I did not know table was a two dimensional array. any other ideas on this?

Comment: Never mind I had something typed wrong i guess Thank you very much for the help I have spent hours looking for this

Comment: Keep in mind that you can post, and accept, answers to your own questions if you figure it out.  It will help others in the future who may have the same issue.